# Como tratar exceção lançada "Integrity constraint violation: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails"?

Tags: php, exceção

Utilizo a classe `PDO` para comunicação com o `banco de dados` e não sei uma forma boa de capturar essa `exceção`.

Procurei uma classe que extende `PDOException` mas não achei.

Posso fazer uma consulta antes de deletar, isso resolve, mas queria tratar quando a exceção é lançada, ou essa não é a melhor forma?

Comment: Toda exceção do tipo "integrity constraint violation" vem com uma mensagem de erro que começa com `SQLSTATE[23000]`. Já tentou tratar sua exceção com base nisso?

Comment: Exatamente isso @RodrigoRigotti, Obrigado, com isso descobri que o objeto da classe PDOException  tem um método `getCode()` devolve exatamento esse numero, obrigado @RodrigoRigotti

Comment: exemplo: `}catch(PDOException $e){ echo $e->getCode();}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há casos em que o `getCode()` da PDOException não retorna o código correto.

Neste caso eu uso:

```
try {
   ....
} catch (PDOException $e) {
   if (isset($e->errorInfo[1]) && $e->errorInfo[1] == '1451') {
      print 'mensagem';
   }
}
```